# C#: Memory is not deallocated when passing an array to a Task

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ProcessMessage(i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ProcessMessage(int i)
    {
        int[]? array = new int[10000000];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            array[j] = i;
        }

        Task.Run(() => ProcessArray(array, i)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static void ProcessArray(int[]? myArray, int number)
    {
        if (myArray == null) return;
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}] Start task");
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}] {myArray[0]}");
        Thread.Sleep((10 - number) * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}] {myArray[0]}");
        myArray = null;
        return;
    }
}
```

I see that the memory of the arrays is not deallocated. Why is that? How can I fix it?
I cannot await the task an set the array to null afterwards.

This code is just an example, in the real code I have an event handler that is executed sequentially, and I need to process the events in parallel. In the event handler I get an array from a `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`. I cannot transform the `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` into an array inside the Task because it needs to be processed BEFORE the event handler returns.

Comment: Why would you expect the arrays to be deallocated? Setting some variables to null does nothing to achieve that. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203.

Comment: C# is a managed language in a garbage-collected environment, meaning that deallocation happens on the Garbage Collector's schedule, not yours. You don't need to fix anything other than your expectations.

Comment: `I see that the memory of the arrays is not deallocated.` How are you determining this?

Comment: I see that the memory increase when I create the arrays and id does not decrease when reaching "Console.ReadLine();". So I guess the GC will collect those arrays whenever he want. My question is if the GC will collect at some time them or is there any weak reference that will prevent it? If I execute a GC.Collect before "Console.ReadLine()" the memory gets collected so it seems its working fine